# Azure swap slots exlude files

Tags: azure, azure-deployment-slots

How to swap slots and at the same time exclude specific files? In my case I need to exclude the robots.txt file during a swap from staging to production.

There is a feature "slot setting" that I'm using for an application setting but this doesn't apply for files.